# Non-Existing Tag Pages Do Not Return 404 Error

Tags: bug, 404-not-found

Non-existing pages should return a 404 error for better SEO.

But any site of StackExchange network does not return 404 errors for non-existing tagged page.

Example 1: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sdfsdfsdfsdfsd

Example 2: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nbsdjkfsdkfksdjkfjsdfsdfsdf

I think this is a bug. Or is there a special reason to allow this (I mean not returning 404) by default?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From a functional perspective it is a search.

When you search for something you expect either search results or *your search didn't return any hits*. None of those cases call for a 404 page. When that happens all people will raise bugs.

See how you searched for a tag:

[image]

I do admit that the page could do with a message that no results match the search criteria, something like that is however present in the [new navigation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/308875/new-navigation-release-candidate) on Stack Overflow:

[image]

**tl;dr;** That is not as bug and certainly doesn't need to do a 404. The particular search state could use some love, maybe backport the new navigation design.

Comment: No need to backport anything, search already supports showing a message (Your search returned no matches.) when there are no results, it just need to be applied to tag search as well. :)

Comment: Whoa @rene you got +208 rep. (offtopic I know)

Comment: @PrittBalagopal That is the first thing I also notice :-D